# Removing whitespaces in HAML

Tags: haml, removing-whitespace

Is there a way to achieve this in HAML?

```
<h1>Lorem ip<span class="red">sum</span><span class="subtitle">dolor</span></h1>
```

I used this online tool conversor (http://html2haml.heroku.com/)

```
%h1
  Lorem ip
  %span.red sum
  %span.subtitle dolor
```

and render this in HTML:

```
<h1>
  Lorem ip
  <span class='red'>sum</span>
  <span class='subtitle'>dolor</span>
</h1>
```

I'm trying to remove the whitespace between **ip** and **sum** but I can't achieve it.

Comment: generally you'd want to do this with inline styles, haml syntax is more ment for blocks. `%h1 Lorem ip<span class="red">sum</span>`

Answer (score 95):

With this:

```
%h1<
  Lorem ip
  %span.red> sum
  %span.subtitle dolor
```

Output looks like this:

```
<h1>Lorem ip<span class="red">sum</span><span class="subtitle">dolor</span></h1>
```

[HAML Whitespace Removal](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#whitespace-removal--and-)

Comment: Thanks for this. How can I do the same in a haml helper : `haml_tag :span do ... end`?

Comment: My guess is you can't because `:>` flag isn't supported. See docs http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#haml_tag-instance_method

Comment: That's what I'm understanding now ... :( I can't even find a workaround to this ...

Comment: updated documentation link: http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_